# Firebase - Generate table from database data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know how to create a table like this[image: this]from some data in a firebase database like this
[image: this]

There would need to be a column for ID, Title, Number of Answers, Correct Answer and Type. Preferably this should be done using jQuery.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does *create a table* mean? Firebase database doesn't have rows and columns nor does it have tables - just parent and child nodes which are key: value pairs (think: Dictionary). What kind of table do you want? A SQL Table? A two dimensional array? A set of classes? What does it need to be a 'table'? We really need more data to provide an answer - perhaps providing us a use case and showing what you've tried so far would help us better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I mean an HTML table

Comment: Have tried Datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Get data

Read the firebase database [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) and [references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot).

The basic firebase read operation looks like this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("location");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key;
    var value = snapshot.val();

    console.log(key + ": " + value);
  });
```

Of course you have to add scripts for [firebase and firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) before.

If you want to loop through an data you can use [forEach](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) function, for example:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("location2");

query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var key = childSnapshot.key;
    var value = childSnapshot.val();

    console.log(key + ": " + value);
  });
});
```

### Table

You can create table dynamically using JS - functions like [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

For example:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var animalsArray = ["Elephant", "Dog", "Cat"];

var table = document.createElement("table");

for (var i = 0; i < animalsArray.length; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td = document.createElement("td");

  td.textContent = animalsArray[i];

  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}

fragment.appendChild(table);
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

### Table built from data in Firebase database

And now connect concepts above together. Create a table. Get data from firebase database. At every ireration over this data: create new table row with cells built from key and value of an element. In example below I used for loop to not duplicate the same operation for every cell.

Full example:

Data tree in Firebase Database:

```
{
  "location2" : {
    "hello" : "world",
    "hi" : "Mark"
  }
}
```

Code:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var table = document.createElement("table");

var query = firebase.database().ref("location2");

query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var trValues = [childSnapshot.key, childSnapshot.val()];

    for (var i = 0; i < trValues.length; i++) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");

      td.textContent = trValues[i];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    table.appendChild(tr);
  });
});

fragment.appendChild(table);
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```